# How to find if a generic type is List<>

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, generic-list

I have a generic method define as below

```
public T MyMethod<T>(extra params)
```

My method can receive and return either single entity type but also List.
How can I find if T passed is a single entity type or a List and in this case how can I get the type of inner type T1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using methods of the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class:

```
var type = typeof(T);
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) {
    var innerType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```